# Forgot how to do non-ajax dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this sounds silly but i forgot how to code non-ajax.
Specifically: 
I am in MVC
I have a dropdown list with languages.
When a language is chosen i want to reload the whole page with the new language.
This all works but I have to manually refresh the page.
I mean I could call window.location.refresh after i return from the action but i feel like i should be able to do a full refresh. Am i suppose to call submit on a form?

I really feel like i am missing osme extremely easy right in front of my face thing.
I have been doing so many partial ajax updates in my life,i lost my plain old post and reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea you have to do a form submit, but whats wrong with window.location.refresh?

Comment: nothing "wrong" per say. I just felt like there was a way to kick off the submit with out extra code. I just felt like i was missing something. guess not

Answer (score 0):

Normally selecting language for a site is independent of other form submissions, and you can get away with a `GET` instead of `POST`. So, in the `onchange` attribute of your select, you can put:

```
var lang = ...//get selected language value here
document.location = 'http://mysite.com/' + lang //or whatever your URL scheme is
```